# Find the fraction of messages that are sent between the same sender and receiver within five minutes

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

A dataset with information around messages sent between users in a P2P messaging application. Below is the dataset's schema:

| Column Name | Data Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| date | string | date of the message sent/received,format is 'YYYY-mm-dd' |
| timestamp | integer | timestamp of the message sent/received, epoch seconds |
| sender_id | integer | id of the message sender |
| receiver_id | integer | id of the message receiver |

My requirement is to find the fraction of messages that are sent between the same sender and receiver within five minutes (e.g. the fraction of messages that receive a response within 5 minutes).

I have tried

`` ` ``
`df = df.sort_values("timestamp", ascending=True)`

`df['timegap'] = df['timestamp'].diff()`

`df['timegap'] = df['timegap'].fillna(0)`

`df['gapinminutes'] = df['timegap']/60`

`df1 = df[df.gapinminutes < 5]`

`df1.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)`

`conversation = 0`

`for i in range(0,len(df1)-1):`

`if df1['sender_id'][i] ==  df1['receiver_id'][i+1] and df1['sender_id'][i+1] ==  df1['receiver_id'][i] :`

`conversation = conversation+1`

`fraction = conversation/len(df)`

Being a novice developer - I need to know if my solution is correct for the requirement and is there a better/simple way to do it

Answer (score 1):

To get a fraction of the conversation between two parties you could calculate the count of messages starting from the first message to five minutes, then divide the count by the length of the data frame to get the fraction. To achieve this first we sort all the rows by timestamps and then groupby sender_id and receiver_id then we resample the timestamps by 5 min intervals and aggregate the sum and keep the first row because that is when the conversation started.

```
df = df.sort_values("timestamp", ascending=True)
df['conversation_fraction'] = df.groupby(['sender_id','receiver_id'])['timestamp'].resample('5min').sum().head(1)
df['conversation_fraction'] = df['conversation_fraction']/len(df)
```